# Selecting values from second column alongside the values from first column in the same row

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I am trying to get values matching the value from the second column. For example, I want to know who is the sender for Bill Gates by only using IDs.

I have two tables,

```
*users* table
| user_ID  | Full_name      |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Steve Jobs     |
| 2        | Bill Gates     |
| 3        | Elon Musk      |

*relationships* table (with both column foreign keys)
| user_sender  | user_receiver  |
| ------------ | -------------- |
| 1            | 2              |
| 3            | 1              |
| 3            | 2              |
```

I want to select based on "user_receiver" column the matching values in the column "user_sender"

For example, I want to know who is user_sender for 2
OUTPUT:

```
|              |                |
| ------------ | -------------- |
| 1            | 2              |
| 3            | 2              |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables  and select the rows you want

you have access to all columns of both tables by addressing them with their alias

```
SELECT u.user_ID  , u.Full_name,r.user_receiver 
 FROM users u JOIN 
relationships r ON u.user_ID = r.user_sender
WHERE r.user_receiver = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look based on the name, then join the relationships to users.

```
SELECT 
  rel.user_sender
, rel.user_receiver
-- , sender.Full_name AS sender_name
-- , receiver.Full_name AS receiver_name
FROM relationships AS rel
JOIN users AS sender ON sender.user_ID = rel.user_sender
JOIN users As receiver ON receiver.user_ID = rel.user_receiver
WHERE receiver.Full_name = 'Bill Gates'
```

If you already know the user_receiver number, and you only want the ID's

```
SELECT *
FROM relationships
WHERE user_receiver = 2
```